# Getting title from a YouTube video and write it in HTML/CSS

Tags: php, html, css, youtube

I'm not the best at web coding, I've only gotten into it recently for a quick project. I'm looking to pull the title from the YouTube video and store it in a variable to which I can write out. Ive never used PHP before, I'm experienced In Java and Python although I have no idea how to set it up on my website.

index.html:

```
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">  

  <iframe width="1" height="1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLsVV8G4dmXyE2mSm3ZSz_AcNVduhw2ZwM&rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>   
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/z6fgaW8.png");
background-color: #cccccc;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

My videos are in a playlist, to clarify: `id` like to pull the `title` from the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and write this in the bottom left corner of the website.

My website does have PHP support, not sure about the others.

[My Website](http://darklegionrp.byethost24.com/)

Please correct any errors ;D
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents(sprintf('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=%s&format=json', urlencode($url))));
if ($result) {
    $title = $result->title;
    $html = $result->html;
    $thumbnail_url = $result->thumbnail_url;
    $height = $result->height;
    $width = $result->width;
    $thumbnail_width = $result->thumbnail_width;
    $thumbnail_height = $result->thumbnail_height;
}
```

Comment: just put that straight into my index.html?

Comment: No, this is a php code. You need to insert into a php file(for example: index.php).

Comment: and this will automatically run or will i need to setup some code in my html? Also how do I set the url for this function?

Comment: this also doesn't answer my question of how I can write this on my webpage?

Comment: :O <3 Wow, so echo will just write it out to which i can then edit the text with css?

Comment: Never used PHP before

Comment: Let me write this in jquery(ajax).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95602/discussion-between-genarated-pixelz-and-alireza-safian).